# PHP - Finding number of consecutive intervals that differ more than 50

Tags: php

I have an array;

```
$arr=array(800,850,800,750,1100,950,950,950,850);
```

I want to find how many times digits changes more than 50. I tried something but I failed. Is there anyone who can help me with that ?

```
for ($i=0 ; $i < count($arrx); $i++ ) { 

    if (abs($arr[$i] - $arr[$i-1]) > 50) {

        $arr[$i] = $arr50[$i];
    }
}
```

I tried something like that but it didn't work. I'm not even sure that it's the way that I should follow.

Thank you.

Comment: So the output should be `3` only or what are you expecting? Also your variables doesn't match in the question. Please clarify your question

Comment: @Andreas yes that's all

Comment: i-1 will be out of bounds. Start at i = 1 for starters. You have a mess of array names: arr, arrx, arr50? What is what? You are also asigning values to the original data array instead of pushing indexes or values to some new array. Hope that helps.

Comment: yes I'm aware of that mess, it helped thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is going to work.

```
$arr=array(800,850,800,750,1100,950,950,950,850);

for ($i=1; $i < count($arr); $i++) { 
if (abs($arr[$i]-$arr[$i-1])>50) {
    $array[]=1;
}
}
echo count($array);
```

Comment: I have one more question, what if I want to say 33.3% of it differ more than 50 ? Do you have any suggestion for it ?

Comment: then replace the last line with this: 
echo number_format(count($array) / count($arr) * 100,2) .' of it differ more than 50.';

Comment: I smell rabbit hole! @TanayAcan you have one count, and you can count() the other. Do you need help with the math?

Comment: @Andreas I know how to calculate percentage but I'm not familliar with php, I need to do it because it's a small part of my project. I'm sorry if it bothered you.

Comment: What bothered me was the rabbit hole thing. You asked one question, got the answer and kept on asking more. Either ask a new question or include the second question in your original post. Asking a answerer to keep adding to their answer is not what SO is about. Sometimes people add so much to their orignial question that the question and accepted answer does not match anymore.

Comment: I understand, it wasn't on my mind when I'm asking the first question. After that, I wondered 'is it possible to calculate percentage with same method?' and asked that. It was my last and extra question. I'm sorry if I was rude and I'm sorry if I'm not clear, English is not my native language.

Comment: No offense taken. And I hope I didn't offend you. I was just pointing out that you can "get in trouble" when doing like this.

Comment: What is the sense of `$array[]=1;`?

Comment: In order to put something to array so that i can count the number of elements in that array.